# JQuery Widget doesnt like controls added at runtime?

Tags: c#, jquery

I have created a page using jquery Tabs widgets, it worked just like the tutorial, if I create the controls on the aspx page. However, I now have a need to generate these controls (Div/UL/LI) from code, so that I can duplicate this multiple times (unknown number) on a single page... but the CSS doesn't seem to apply, and the widget doesn't function.

page.aspx:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

page.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            accordion.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;


            var divTabs = new HtmlGenericControl("div");            
            divTabs.ID = "tabs";
            divTabs.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
            accordion.Controls.Add(divTabs);

            var ulMain = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");
            divTabs.Controls.Add(ulMain);

            var il1 = new HtmlGenericControl("il");           
            il1.InnerHtml = "<a href=\"#tabs-1\">Tab 1</a>";
            ulMain.Controls.Add(il1);
            var il2 = new HtmlGenericControl("il");            
            il2.InnerHtml = "<a href=\"#tabs-2\">Tab 2</a>";
            ulMain.Controls.Add(il2);

            var divTab1 = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
            divTab1.ID = "tabs-1";
            divTab1.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
            divTabs.Controls.Add(divTab1);

            var parTag = new HtmlGenericControl("p");            
            divTab1.Controls.Add(parTag);

            var divTab2 = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
            divTab2.ID = "tabs-2";
            divTab2.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
            divTabs.Controls.Add(divTab2);

            var parTag2 = new HtmlGenericControl("p");
            parTag2.ID = "parTab2";
            divTab2.Controls.Add(parTag2);

            Label lbl1 = new Label();
            Label lbl2 = new Label();

            lbl1.Text = "HERE IS SECTION 1";
            lbl2.Text = "HERE IS SECTION 2";

            parTag.Controls.Add(lbl1);
            parTag2.Controls.Add(lbl2);
        }
```

When I set this up in the aspx file the Tabs widget works perfectly. when I do this in the code, the Tab Text have no formatting, and I see the content from both tabs at once. Im sure that this is just a rookie mistake that I am making, so I figured that someone here would just know how I am screwing this up!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if you have to change var il1 = new HtmlGenericControl("il"); to var il1 = new HtmlGenericControl("li");

Comment: OMG. I was staring at it for so long that it all started to blend. Thank you so much for catching that. All is well again, minus my ego!